# Showing Recent Messages error: Could not get GOOGLE_APP_ID in Google Services file from build environment

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

Just shown up on my Xcode a couple of hours ago and none of the other stack overflow answers are working. Anybody know how to fix this? My project won't build or archive(currently using Xcode 10.2) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To fix this error, Make sure you have firebase script above the "Copy bundle resources" in Build phases section of your target in Xcode.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Google Firebase.

As the error say your GOOGLE_APP_ID could not be found.

**Solution**

Drag "**GoogleService-Info.plist**" in your project folder. This configuration file is generated when creating your project. If you don't have it you might want to regenerate it again as described on [Firebase Console](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592)